# How to access data in iPhone backup file directly

Tags: iphone, ios, backup

I have just gotten rid of my iPhone 5 but did a full  backup of picture and such beforehand. I do not plan on getting another iPhone. Is there a way i can get my content back? I have the backup file location but the files are not what i expected them to be.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [iPhone / iPod Touch Backup Extractor](http://supercrazyawesome.com) (for Mac) and [iPhone Backup Extractor](http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com) (for Windows).

> Recover lost iPhone calendar events, contacts, photos, videos, SMS messages, notes, location data and app data from iTunes backup files.

[image: iPhone Backup Extractor screenshot]